# Use prepared statement into creating temporary table

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to change existing table and insert the result into temporary table with memoery engine

1) Step - I swaped rows and columns from existing table

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(`parameterId` = ', `parameterId`, ',`valueId`,NULL)) AS parameter', `parameterId`)
  ) INTO @sql
FROM product_parameter;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT productId , ', @sql , ' FROM product_parameter GROUP BY productId');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
```

When I execute the stmt statement it will show me a the result

2) Step - I would like to insert the result to temporary table or for testing into physical table

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temporaryTable ENGINE=MEMORY AS
```

Is it possible to acomplish my goal by one query? Or should i create table then somehow add the result data?

Answer (score -1):

You should create the temporary table and the populate it.